# How to use Bootstrap tooltip on input elements?

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not 100% sure this is at all possible, because `input` doesn't have a `rel` attribute (the example on the Bootstrap website shows only 1 example with `rel="tooltip"`), but I think it should work.

This is my HTML:

```
<input id="password" type="password" />
```

And this is how I try to trigger it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[id=password]').tooltip({'trigger':'focus'});
});
```

And I also tried this:

```
$('#password').tooltip({'trigger':'focus'});
```

And none of them seem to work. I eventually want to trigger it manually, but this is the first step. 
Does anybody know a solution for this? Is it possible at all? Thanks.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try to specify "title" parameter to tooltip. Like:

```
$('#password').tooltip({'trigger':'focus', 'title': 'Password tooltip'});
```

Btw, that's nothing wrong with input element having "rel" attribute.

Comment: Actually, `rel` attributes are not valid for `input` fields. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen: That may be the true, but in this specific case it is not. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4 does not list `rel` as an attribute. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-rel says that it "describes the relationship from the current document to the anchor specified by the `href` attribute." And since `input` doesn't does not have an `href`, I conclude it is not valid.

Comment: `hover focus` is default, too, so you may not have to set that property. Also, probably good to point out that you should include `'container': 'body'` as a property too, if you're working within a `.btn-group` or `.input-group` see [Tooltips in button groups and input groups require special settings](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-examples).

Answer (score 14):

In case anyone wants to know more generic tooltip option for the all the text boxes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[rel="txtTooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" rel="txtTooltip" title="**Your Title**" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
```

Answer (score 4):

**Boostrap 3 and 4**

Based on @Senthil's response, and using bootstrap 3.x or 4.x and JQuery, this will set tooltips for all input elements as long as the `title` property is set without the need of the `rel` attribute.

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" id="inputTestID" name="inputTest" placeholder="Test" type="text" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip Text">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').tooltip();
});
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #fff; 
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

- [Bootstrap 3 Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stn5efuq/).
- [Bootstrap 4 Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foxwhy4v/).

Answer (score 3):

This may be useful for those having multiple input fields, so you don't end up calling several tooltip(),

Just do this, this is based on ID of input field, you could have it to work as class too;

```
$('input').each(function (i, e) {
    var label;
    switch ($(e).attr('id')) {
        case 'input-one':
            label = 'This is input #1';
            break;
        case 'input-two':
            label = 'This is input #2';
            break;
    }
    $(e).tooltip({ 'trigger': 'focus', 'title': label });
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**Enable tooltips everywhere**

One way to initialize all tooltips on a page would be to select them by their data-bs-toggle attribute:

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not use data-toggle attribute as a trigger a tooltip if present?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">
  Tooltip on bottom
</button>
```