# Jquery not Triggering Bootstrap ToolTips properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have multiple input fields on a page, and I'm trying to trigger a Jquery event. Each box has it's own Bootstrap tooltip and, when the cursor is in the relevant box, I want the tooltip to appear. However, with my current code, I have to clickout of the box and back in the for the tooltip to appear.

Here is my Jquery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input').focus(function(){
     var box = $(document.activeElement).attr("id")
     console.log(box)
     $('#' + box).tooltip({
        placement: "bottom",
        trigger: "focus"
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371948/how-to-use-bootstrap-tooltip-on-input-elements

Comment: I think have a redundant focus event...