# simple_form tooltip component on bootstrap input-group wrapper not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I created an [issue on their github](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1361) but figured I would ask this community since it leans a little outside of the simple_form universe.

I have successfully added bootstrap custom wrappers using [their wiki instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/How-to-use-Bootstrap-3-input-group-in-Simple-Form).

I have also added the tooltip helper to these components by following [these instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Bootstrap-component-helpers#tooltips-helper). Slightly modified to use translation files. See below.

The problem, however, is that the tooltips only work when there is no `input-group` used. It would seem that the attributes set on the wrapper are not propagating down to the inputs inside?

Has anyone else seen this or gotten around this? Below are the important bits.

Here is how I am defining the custom wrapper with the tooltip.

```
config.wrappers :horizontal_input_group, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-4 control-label'
  b.use :tooltip

  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-8' do |ba|
    ba.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-group col-sm-12' do |append|
      append.use :input, class: 'form-control'
    end

    ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end
end
```

And here is how I am calling it in my form.

```
= f.input :peak_visibility, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group, label: 'Peak Audience Visibility' do
  = f.input_field :peak_visibility, class: 'form-control' 
  %span{class: 'input-group-addon'} %
```

And here is the tooltip helper file I added to simple-from.

```
module SimpleForm
  module Components
    module Tooltips
      def tooltip(wrapper_options = nil)
        unless tooltip_text.nil?
          input_html_options[:rel] ||= 'tooltip'
          input_html_options['data-toggle'] ||= 'tooltip'
          input_html_options['data-placement'] ||= tooltip_position
          input_html_options['data-trigger'] ||= 'focus'
          input_html_options['data-original-title'] ||= tooltip_text
          nil
        end
      end

      def tooltip_text
        tooltip = options[:tooltip]
        if tooltip.is_a?(String)
          tooltip
        elsif tooltip.is_a?(Array)
          tooltip[1]
        else
          nil
        end
      end

      def tooltip_position
        tooltip = options[:tooltip]
        tooltip.is_a?(Array) ? tooltip[0] : "right"
      end
    end
  end
end

SimpleForm::Inputs::Base.send(:include, SimpleForm::Components::Tooltips)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the twitter-bootstrap gem, but maybe this could help you.

Add a data-toggle and title to your html input and respective script in your view.

For example:

```
<label data-original-title="Very Good" for="evaluation" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title=""></label>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
      });
</script>
```

You can also use the label/input rails helpers with data and title args:

```
<%= f.label :evaluation, "Evaluation:", data: {toggle: "tooltip", placement: "bottom" }, title: "Very Good" %>
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371948/how-to-use-bootstrap-tooltip-on-input-elements) to help you!

Comment: this does not seem to be addressing the question which is specifically to do with how this rails gem is outputting the html.

Comment: this code worked for me in a different situation, appreciated